# Displaying Parse.com data via SDK in React Native

Tags: parse-platform, reactjs, react-native

I've just started with React Native and I'm sure I'm missing something small. However, for the life of me I can't figure out how to display this.data.mission.XX anywhere. I can console log the data and see it in Xcode, but that's it.

```
var React = require('react-native');
var Parse = require('parse/react-native');
var ParseReact = require('parse-react/react-native');

var {
  Component,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  Text,
  View,
  StatusBarIOS,
} = React;

var CountdownClock = require('./CountdownClock');

var CountdownScreen = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ParseReact.Mixin],

  getInitialState: function() {
    return{
        mission: null,
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    StatusBarIOS.setStyle('light-content');
  },

  observe: function() {
    return {
      mission: (new Parse.Query('mission')).equalTo('featuredMission', true)
    };
  },

  render: function() {
    console.log(this.data.mission);
      return (
      <Image source={{uri: '#'}} style={styles.backgroundImage}>
          <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
            <View style={styles.clock}>
              <CountdownClock />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.featured}>
              <Text style={styles.header}> Name: {this.data.mission.missionName} </Text>
              <Text style={styles.header}> Estimated Start: {this.data.mission.windowStart}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.header}> Site: {this.data.mission.missionSite}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.header}> Vehicle: {this.data.mission.missionVehicle}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.description}>{this.data.mission.missionDescription}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
      </Image>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account that this.data is logging out, you probably need to do something like this:

Set the data property in the state:

```
getInitialState(){
  data: {}
}
```

Attach this.data to the state:

```
componentWillUpdate() {
  this.setState({
    data: this.data
  })
}
```

Use this.state.data vs this.data

```
<View style={styles.featured}>
    <Text style={styles.header}> Name: {this.state.data.mission.missionName} </Text>
    <Text style={styles.header}> Estimated Start: {this.state.data.mission.windowStart}</Text>
    <Text style={styles.header}> Site: {this.state.data.mission.missionSite}</Text>
    <Text style={styles.header}> Vehicle: {this.state.data.mission.missionVehicle}</Text>
    <Text style={styles.description}>{this.state.data.mission.missionDescription}</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: I changed getInitialState to return data: {}, and did the this.setState data: this.data in componentDidMount; however, I'm still having the same problem. I can console.log(this.state.data); and it gives me my object in the Xcode console, but it's not displaying in my view.

Comment: Hmmm sorry about that. After looking at this: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseReact/issues/15 , maybe try componentWillUpdate()  (see updated answer)?